# Case statement not returning null when expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a case statement that is using logic to strip out order numbers. However I cannot figure out why certain values are being returned instead of `null`

[image: Results]

```
t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef t3,
t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef t2,
                case
                    when        t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef IS NOT NULL 
                    and         t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef LIKE '%-%' or t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef LIKE '%_%' 
                        then    
                            case    when t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef LIKE '%-%' 
                                        then LEFT(t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef, charindex('-', t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef) - 2) 
                                    when t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef LIKE '%_%' 
                                        then LEFT(t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef, charindex('_', t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef) - 2) 
                            end
                    when        t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef LIKE '%-%' 
                    and         ASCII(LEFT(t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef, charindex('-', t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef)) ) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 
                        then        replace(LEFT(t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef, charindex('-', t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef) - 1), '-', '')
                    when        t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef LIKE '%_%'
                        then        SUBSTRING(t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef, CHARINDEX('_',t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef) + 1, LEN(t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef))
                    else        null
                end                                                                                     as omOrder
```

So when t3 is not null, pull out the 7 digit number on the right

when t3 is null pull the 7 digit number from t2

Why does the else null not handle the value in row 3 of the results? omOrder should be null in this instance.

**How do I get a null for omOrder when t3 is null and t2 doesnt include a _ or - as shown in row 3 of the results**

*The logic also handles occasions when the values in t2 and t3 are separated by -*

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement -- there may be a simpler way.

Comment: You have a `CASE` **Expression**.  T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions. The former can only return a scalar value; it doesn't operator like a logic flow operator, or provide boolean results.

Comment: I'll bet its because of the `AND` and `OR` combination in the first `WHEN`. You don't need to check for `NULL` there anyway. If you do want the `NULL` check, use parentheses: `t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef IS NOT NULL AND (t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef LIKE '%-%' OR t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef LIKE '%_%')`

Comment: @GordonLinoff please see new comments

Answer (score 0):

If this is the logic you want:

> So when t3 is not null, pull out the 7 digit number on the right
>
> when t3 is null pull the 7 digit number from t2

Then the logic would be:

```
select coalesce(right(t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef, 7),
                right(t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef, 7)
               )
```

If you need to validate that there is, indeed, a 7-digit number, then `case` can be used:

```
select (case when t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
             then right(t3.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef, 7)
             when t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
             then right(t2.LMS_SalesOrder_ExternalRef, 7)
        end)
```

Comment: when t3 or t2 contain a - instead of _, the values are reversed e.g JDS71818_4938216  or 4938216-JDS71818

Comment: How do I get a null for omOrder when t3 is null and t2 doesnt include a _ or - as shown in row 3 of the results?